# fscanf not reading char from file

Tags: c, file-io, scanf

I have a program that reads from a file and converts assembly code into VM machine code. Instructions have different datatypes depending on the opcode, so my reader looks like this:

```
while(!feof(inF)) {
    fscanf(inF, "%s",&temp); //analyse first string and branch into if statement 
        printf("%s\n", temp);
        if (strcmp(temp, "NOP") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "nop") == 0) {
            fprintf(outF, "%i\n", 0);
        }
        else if (strcmp(temp, "LDI") == 0 || strcmp(temp, "ldi") == 0) {
            opcode = LDI; //opcode 1
            fscanf(inF," %c %d", &r1, &immediate); //get r1 and immediate
            printf("R1: %i\n", r1);
            printf("I: %i\n", immediate);
            r1 = getReg(r1);
            r2 = 0;
            subop = 0;
            output = (opcode << 27)|(r1 << 24)|(r2 << 21)|(subop << 16)|(immediate);
            fprintf(outF, "%x\n", output);
        }        
}
```

With a line reading `LDI A 1024`, I get an output of :

```
LDI
R1: 0
I: 1024
```

Instead of the expected

```
LDI
R1: 65
I: 1024
```

It appears that `fscanf` is not reading the `char`. I've looked at solutions that seemed to work for others and they don't seem to work here for some reason.

Comment: `fscanf(inF," %c %d", &r1, &immediate);` --> `fscanf(inF," %i %d", &r1, &immediate);` assuming `r1` is `int`

Comment: what is the type of `r1`?

Comment: A side note on why `while(!feof(inF))` is wrong: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: r1's type is char

Comment: What would you recommend for the file loop then?

Comment: Can you post a small complete example program demonstrating the issue, so that we can run it and check?

Comment: Yeah, here you go: http://pastebin.com/6RUAXX3s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the variable `immediate` as `unsigned short` while the line

```
fscanf(inF," %c %d", &r1, &immediate);
```

supposes it is an integer. The behavior is undefined in such cases.

Comment: I'll try changing the type and adding a cast to `unsigned short` after getting the value

Comment: Okay, this gets the desired result, but then it proceeds to give me the same result as above after returning the correct values for some reason.

Comment: Okay never mind I fixed that problem by adding a `return;` at the end of the if statement.